# ADB Shell does not have permission to acces

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to install apk to work profile user

```
adb shell pm install --user 12 /data/test.apk
```

adb returned error.

```
C:\Users\tesrter\Downloads>adb shell pm install --user 12 /data/test.apk
Security exception: Shell does not have permission to access user 12
 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:14895 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:3834 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:2756

java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 12
 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:14895 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:3834 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:2756
        at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:1883)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14895)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:3834)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2756)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2762)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1072)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:175)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:24259)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:888)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:772)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4879)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4661)
        at com.android.server.pm.HwPackageManagerService.onTransact(HwPackageManagerService.java:534)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1028)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1001)
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: it's 2023 and now I'm getting:
adb shell pm list packages
Exception occurred while executing 'list':
java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 10. if I only knew why it popped up...

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. No one out there to help?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.  I found that I could solve by running as primary user:

```
pm list packages --user 0
```

That was able to show me all the apps that were installed that I had the ability to delete.

Comment: It says, command not found: pm

Comment: @SagarPatel you should use adb shell pm list packages --user 0.

Comment: This worked for me, too. 
from ADB:
`adb shell cmd package list packages --user 0`
To list specific packages only, one can filter using:
`adb shell cmd "package list packages --user 0 | grep <SEARCH-TERM>"`

Answer (score 0):

elaborating a bit on [danch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21122356/danch)'s original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75738220/9899528). If you want to filter the list according to a `<SEARCH-TERM>`, then you will need extra `"`s to pipe the result to `grep`, like this:

`adb shell cmd "package list packages --user 0 | grep <SEARCH-TERM>"`